# Some questions about heat flow in this example

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

I'm new at heat transfer and I have three elementary questions from the book "Fundamentals of heat transfer" by Incropera et al. This is Example 1.1 in the book:

[image]

(1) What is the definition of steady-state conditions? The authors haven't define them before in the book.

(2) The authors have written this comment at the end of the example: Note the direction of heat flow and the distinction between heat flux and heat rate. What is the definition of heat flow? They've defined the concepts of heat flux and heat rate but not heat flow. Can anyone tells me what is the direction of heat flow in this example?

(3) What is the relationships of heat flow to a temperature gradient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so for?

Comment: @ChetMiller I don't have the definitions to think about them. I know that energy transfer accur in the direction of decreasing temperature and the heat flux is in the $x$ direction and prependicular to the direction of transfer. Moreover, I think steady-state condition means temperature doesn't change with time at any point in the system. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, on all points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction

Comment: @ChetMiller Could you please help me about the questions (2) and (3)?

Comment: I once worked with Incropera's daughter Terri. Super smart woman.

Answer (score 0):

Heat flux q is flow of heat per unit area.  Heat flow Q is total flow rate of heat (J/s).  $$q=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$$$$Q=Aq$$